# Difference between current and voltage waves with the transverse electromagnetic waves on a transmission line

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, reflection

In a transmission line consisting of 2 parallel wires, one can show that the voltage and current exist as a wave propagating along the wire.

When calculating, for example, the reflection coefficient due to an unmatched load, one uses the waveforms $$V_0e^{i(\omega t - kz)}$$ $$I_0e^{i(\omega t - kz)}$$ to derive the result. However, why do we not use $$E_0e^{i(\omega t - kz)}$$ $$H_0e^{i(\omega t - kz)}$$ (representing the propagating E and H fields) for this derivation?

Essentially what I am unsure of is the difference between the propagating voltage and current waves with the propagating EM waves in a transmission line. Are they one of the same thing?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations

Answer (score 0):

The E field and the voltage are the same thing.  The current is its own thing, it depends on the impedance of the line and the voltage or E.  The magnetic field is its own thing but depends on the current.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but then why is it that when we calculate the reflection coefficient that we use the voltage and current wave instead?

Comment: Usually when calculating reflection coefficient we are concerned with efficiency, or how much energy or power is transferred or reflected, so V and I are convenient because impedance is considered to get I and P=VI.

Comment: I see, and I guess even if we were to use H instead of I then we just multiply everything by a constant so they would cancel anyway?

Comment: Impedance can be complex, so getting I from V is the key.  I don't remember all the details, but H is proportional to rate of change of current.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of convenience: voltage and current in the wires are related to the electric and magnetic fields via the Maxwell equations - we can, find ones once we know the others. When we deal with a rectangular or cylindrical wave guide, dealing with electric and magnetic field is preferable, since the there is no clear way to define voltage and current in this case - e.g., voltage is measured between two points, and the choice of these two points in a cross-section of the wave-guide is somewhat arbitrary. For two parallel wires, voltage is straightforwardly defined as the potential difference between the two wires at the specified cross-section, whereas the electric and magnetic fields have a rather complex structure in the space between the wires.